# Beginner Haskell: Making a last function with reverse

Tags: function, haskell, types

I'm attempting to make a function that generates the last item in a list. I want to use reverse and !!. This is what I have so far:

```
myLast :: [a] -> [a] -> Int -> a
myLast xs = (reverse xs) !! 1
```

I know the problem lies somewhere within the type, but I'm having trouble identifying how to fix it.

Comment: Aren't arrays zero-based in Haskell? Does it work if you use `!! 0` instead of 1?

Comment: By the way, clarifying your exact problem would help; do you get a compiletime error? A runtime error? Does it run but not behave as expected? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function's type signature has nothing to do with what you use *in* the function, it only describes how other people can use this function *you're defining*. So by writing

```
myLast :: [a] -> [a] -> Int -> a
```

you're saying, users need to supply two lists and and integer. Just to get the last element of one of the lists?? That doesn't make sense.

You surely mean

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
```

You should generally write that down *before even thinking* about how you're going to implement that function.

With that signature, you can write various implementations:

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast xs = head $ reverse xs

myLast' :: [a] -> a
myLast' [l] = l
myLast' (_:xs) = myLast' xs

myLast'' :: [a] -> a
myLast'' = fix $ \f (x:xs) -> maybe x id . teaspoon $ f xs
```

or whatever weird implementation you choose, it has nothing to do with the signature.

On an unrelated note: though `last` is actually a standard function from the prelude, it's a [kind of function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) avoided in modern Haskell: `last []` gives an error, because the *is* no `a` value to be found in the empty list! Errors are bad. Hence the “ideal” way to write it is actually

```
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast [] = Nothing
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

Comment: @Bergi: well, actually it didn't work the way I first wrote it: I was just making the point that you can use arbitrary things within the function body without it affecting the signature. But `myLast` wasn't really meant serious, hence the ellipsis... But alright, I now changed it so it does work. Basically, the idea is trying to pop elements off the list in an infinite loop (implemented by fixpoint recursion). Instead of an ordinary termination condition, I _use_ the fact that `last []` gives an error, and catch that exception with [`spoon`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon).

Comment: Oh wow. I understood that it wasn't serious, but didn't grasp how crazy it really was :-) I had never encountered teaspoons as well, so thanks for the example and link!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using `!!` at all, but to use `head`.

```
myLast xs = head (reverse xs)
```

Head returns the first element of the list it is given as argument.
If you insist on using `!!`, in Haskell arrays are indeed zero-based, which means that `!! 0` gets the first element, `!! 1` the second, etc.

<strike>As for the type: `myLast` takes an array of some type and returns one item of that same type. That is denoted as follows:</strike>

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
```

@leftaroundabout covered this way better in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @leftaroundabout 's answer, here's an implementation that should do what you want:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x

myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast [] = Nothing
myLast xs = safeHead $ reverse xs
```

The `Maybe` type is constructed as follows (from [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#Maybe)):

```
data  Maybe a  =  Nothing | Just a
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

`myLast [1, 2, 3, 4]`, for example, will return `Just 4`. If you want to use the value `4` you can use the function `fromJust` function from the [`Data.Maybe` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-Maybe.html#fromJust) (`fromJust (Just 4)` returns `4`). `fromJust` is defined like this:

```
-- | The 'fromJust' function extracts the element out of a 'Just' and
-- throws an error if its argument is 'Nothing'.
--
-- ==== __Examples__
--
-- Basic usage:
--
-- >>> fromJust (Just 1)
-- 1
--
-- >>> 2 * (fromJust (Just 10))
-- 20
--
-- >>> 2 * (fromJust Nothing)
-- *** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
--
fromJust          :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust Nothing  = error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing" -- yuck
fromJust (Just x) = x
```